# How can I test whether C++ is using openmp?

Tags: c++, g++, openmp

I have a program that does independent computations on a bunch of images.  This seems like a good idea to use OpenMP:

```
//file: WoodhamData.cpp
#include <omp.h>

...

void WoodhamData::GenerateLightingDirection() {
    int imageWidth = (this->normalMap)->width();
    int imageHeight = (this->normalMap)->height();
    #pragma omp paralell for num_threads(2)
    for (int r = 0; r < RadianceMaps.size(); r++) {
        if (omp_get_thread_num() == 0){
            std::cout<<"threads="<<omp_get_num_threads()<<std::endl;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

In order to use OpenMP, I add `-fopenmp` to my makefile, so it outputs:

```
g++ -g -o test.exe src/test.cpp src/WoodhamData.cpp -pthread -L/usr/X11R6/lib -fopenmp --std=c++0x -lm -lX11 -Ilib/eigen/ -Ilib/CImg
```

However, I am sad to say, my program reports `threads=1` (run from terminal `./test.exe ...`)

Does anyone know what might be wrong?  This is the slowest part of my program, and it would be great to speed it up a bit.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and look at the warnings.

Comment: @Zboson thanks, this gave me exactly what I needed! Showed me exactly the problem kjpus pointed out.  Curse my poor grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OpenMP directive is wrong - it is "parallel" not "paralell".

Comment: This should have been left as a comment I think. You could have suggested to use `-Wall` so that the OP finds other typos in the future.

Comment: This is my bad, the question in the title is technically different than the one I put in the body.  @Zboson 's answer was the one I wanted, but this answer the question in the body correctly.  I must consult the stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: @Kenkron, many times I did not get the results I wanted because of typos in pragma statments. I wasted a lot of time doing printf debugging which never found the problem with the pragma statement. Since then I have learned to use `-Wall` more.  This is probably a weakness of OpenMP. Normal C code would give a syntax error but you don't necessarily get syntax errors with pragma statements.  That's an interesting question. I wonder if you can enable a option to treat unknown pragma statements as errors to aboard compiling.  `-Werror` is too harsh sometimes I think.

Comment: @Kenkron, `-Wunknown-pragmas`. Now we just need to find a way to have it error on `unknown-pragmas` instead of give a warning and only error on this warning and not all warnings.

Comment: @Kenkron, I think `-Werror=unknown-pragmas` might do it.

Comment: @Kenkron, yes `-Werror=unknown-pragmas` works. I almost wished this was enabled by default with `-fopenmp`. That certainly would have saved me a lot of debugging time in the past.

Comment: @Zboson Thanks for the further clarification. This is very helpful.  If you put your suggestion as an answer, I will mark it correct.

Comment: @Kenkron, I just realized one reason it's not enabled by default. OpenMP is designed so that if you don't enabled Openmp with `-fopenmp` you get the serial code. But if you don't use `-fopenmp` but use `-Werror=unknown-pragmas` with code that has correct OpenMP syntax it won't compile. So there is no ideal solution yet (you could use macros to check if OpenMP is defined but then things start to get ugly). I guess this is one reason some C++ people hate OpenMP.